# ¿Cómo puedo realiza estas operaciones?

Tags: python

Cómo puedo almacenar a una lista estos elementos:

-atraccion1 = Atraccion("Montaña Rusa", "Emocionante montaña rusa", 1.69, 50)

-atraccion2 = Atraccion("Carrusel", "Tranquilo carrusel para niños", 80.0, 30)

-atraccion3 = Atraccion("Casa del Terror", "Atracción de miedo", 1.69, 40)

-atraccion4 = Atraccion("Autos Chocones", "Divertidos autos chocones", 1.69, 10)

```
class ParqueAtracciones:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__atracciones = []
        


    def agregar_atraccion(self,atraccion):
        if not isinstance(atraccion, Atraccion):
            raise ValueError("Se espera una instancia de la clase Atraccion.")
    


    def editar_atraccion(self, atraccion_nombre, nueva_descripcion, nueva_altura_minima, nueva_capacidad_maxima):
        for atraccion in self.__atracciones:
            if atraccion._Atraccion__nombre == atraccion_nombre:
                atraccion._Atraccion__descripcion = nueva_descripcion
                atraccion._Atraccion__altura_minima = nueva_altura_minima
                atraccion._Atraccion__capacidad_maxima = nueva_capacidad_maxima
            print(f"Se editó la atracción {atraccion_nombre} con éxito.")
            
    def eliminar_atraccion(self, atraccion_nombre):
        for atraccion in self.__atracciones:
            if atraccion.__nombre == atraccion_nombre:
                self.__atracciones.remove(atraccion)
```

Comment: Hola Amauri, ¿cual es exactamente el problema? Agregar el objeto a al lista (atributo de instancia `__atracciones`) es simplemente usar `list.append` igual que se hace en `eliminar_atraccion` con `list.remove`, es decir `self.__atracciones.append(atraccion)`

Comment: Es q ya lo he intentado y no me muestra nada, todo en blanco

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agregar lo que has intentado y el problema/error concreto que tienes. Seria simplemente agregar la linea `self.__atracciones.append(atraccion)` en el método `agregar_atraccion` debajo del `if` (al mismo nivel que el `if`, no a nivel del `raise`). Después es simplemente usar el método y pasarle una instancia de `Atracciones` como `parque = ParqueAtracciones()`; `atraccion1 = Atraccion("Montaña Rusa", "Emocionante montaña rusa", 1.69, 50)`; `parque.agregar_atraccion(atraccion1)`

Comment: Por favor muestra lo que intentaste.

Comment: Ya está resuelto, muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParqueAtracciones:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__atracciones = []

    def agregar_atraccion(self, atraccion):
        if not isinstance(atraccion, Atraccion):
            raise ValueError("Se espera una instancia de la clase Atraccion.")
        self.__atracciones.append(atraccion)
        print(f"Se agregó la atracción {atraccion._Atraccion__nombre} con éxito.")

parque = ParqueAtracciones()
atraccion1 = Atraccion("Destructor", "Destruye", 1.60, 25)
parque.agregar_atraccion(atraccion1)

# Imprimir los detalles de las atracciones
for atraccion in parque._ParqueAtracciones__atracciones:
    print(f"Nombre: {atraccion._Atraccion__nombre}, Descripción: {atraccion._Atraccion__descripcion}, Altura mínima: {atraccion._Atraccion__altura_minima}, Capacidad máxima: {atraccion._Atraccion__capacidad_maxima}")
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o es una edición a tu pregunta? Si es lo primero: pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona. Si es lo segundo: edita tu pregunta. Y no olvides modificar el título de tu pregunta, ya que no es nada descriptivo.

Answer (score 0):

soy Djkire. bienvenido:
recuerda que para almacenar 1 dato en una lista sería algo así

```
lista = [] #creamos lista vacia 

lista.append("hola")

print(lista)
```

ahora si quieres almacenar varios elementos. la funcion (extend) lo hará:

```
atraccion1 = [] #creamos lista vacia 

atraccion1.extend(["Montaña Rusa", "Emocionante montaña rusa", 1.69, 50]) #añadimos datos

print(atraccion1) #imprimirá datos añadidos.
```

saludos.